# Get the content of a div by class name using Web Browser control?

Tags: c#, .net

I have a form with `webBrowser1` control that is used to load a page that contains in its HTML part the following line:

```
 ...
 <div class="cls">
 Hello World !
 </div>
```

I need to get the `innerText` of the `div` element. I tried the following:

```
 string result = "";
 foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("div"))
                if (el.GetAttribute("class") == "cls")
                {
                    result = el.InnerText;
                }
```

But the code above doesn't seem to work, and according [to Solution 1 for a similar question on another website](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/271651/read-data-from-DIV-tag-via-webBrowser-Csharp), it is stated that

> First thing which caught my eye is: `<div class="thin">` does not define the name of the `div` element, it defines its CSS style class. Instead, use the attribute name (or both), for example: `<div class="thin" name="thin">`.

How can I get the `innerText` of the `div` element, if there is a `class` attribute only?

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You should use `ClassName` instead of `class`:

```
 if (el.GetAttribute("className") == "cls") { … }
```

For details, see [HtmlElement.GetAttribute("class") doesn't run](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxbcl/thread/66677b14-f34f-4d4e-9a03-326839bb536e/).

Answer (score 1):

Add `runat="server"` and `ID` attributes to the `div` as follows:

```
 …
 <div class="cls" ID="hello_div" runat="server">
 Hello World !
 </div>
```

After adding `runat="server"` attribute, you can use it calling by `ID` on the code behind like an object:

```
string result = hello_div.InnerText; // or InnerHtml
```

Comment: I cannot do that. I do not have access to the html documents

Answer (score 0):

```
        HtmlDocument doc = webBrowser1.Document;
        HtmlElementCollection divs = doc.GetElementsByTagName("div");

        foreach (HtmlElement div in divs)
        {
            try
            {
                var info = div.DomElement;
                PropertyInfo[] pi = info.GetType().GetProperties();

                string strClass = pi[0].GetValue(div.DomElement).ToString();

                if (strClass == "cls")
                {
                        //DoStuff
                }
            }
            catch
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: always add explanation while answering any question